# JavaScript In Netbeans (Google Maps)

Tags: javascript, java, netbeans, maps, jeditorpane

Ok, so I want to be able to use my EditorPane to display a webpagein Netbeans 7.3.1. The code that I was able to get for that is:

```
       try {
    JEditorPane    website = new JEditorPane("https://www.google.co.za/maps/search/Maps/@-29.774368,30.9894242,12z/data=!3m1!4b1");   
       website.setEditable(false);

    JFrame map = new JFrame("Online Map");
    map.add(new JScrollPane(website));
    map.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
    map.setVisible(true);
    map.pack();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("ERROR");
    }
```

So now this code can open say Google.com (That part would be the url), however it will not open Google Maps and stays as a white screen. I do not know why this is happening, but the only idea that I have is that I need to enable JavaScript (Like when you enable it in a normal browser) So I was wondering if anyone knew of a plugin for netbeans or code that would allow me to install/Add/enable/use JavaScript to be able to view these maps. Any help would be appreciated, or if you know of another way to use Google Maps with a set destination, please share with me, Thanks.

Jamie

Comment: `JEditorPane ` is a limited html viewer. try javafx browser or other library

Comment: Ok Thank you, which JavaFX is a browser though sorry? I only have the JavaFX Main Class, Preloader Class, FXML and In swing main class D: Ive never worked with FX before ...